# Smoothing edges in a colormap image

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I have a square matrix of size 'n' which is made of  numbers (1 to N) irregular but clustered.For example all 7's together, all 10's together, etc, but irregularly.   Using "image and colormap" command I get a matrix where each cluster is colored differently but with square edges.. Now I want to ruffle the edges so that there is a smooth boundary between each color. Basically I need ramps in place of steps!  I am a beginner in MATLAB.  Pl Help...........

Answer (score 3):

You can convolve your array with any kind of low-pass (i.e. smoothing) filter. If you want your ramps to be straight lines, you can use an average filter; if you want the ramps to be sigmoidal, you can use a Gaussian filter. The size of the filter window determines the width of the ramp.

For example, to use a 3x3 average filter (which will give ramps of width 3 pixel), you'd do the following:

```
%# pad the image by twice replicating borders to avoid border effects
%# use padarray instead if you have the image processing toolbox
tmp = img([1 1 1:end end end],[1 1 1:end end end]);
%# apply the convolution. Normalize the filter so that the sum
%# of all pixels in the filter is 1, and use the 'valid' option
%# to automatically discard the padding.
smoothImg = conv2(tmp,ones(3)/9,'valid');
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try oversampling your image, and feed it through a low-pass filter.

Answer (score 0):

display the image using pcolor, then type shading interp

```
pcolor(matrix); %or pcolor(x,y,matrix)
shading interp;
```